# Multiple inheritence in Kotlin

Tags: multiple-inheritance, kotlin

Consider the following example

```
public class SomeActivity() : Activity(), OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(Bundle?: savedInstanceState) {
        super<Activity>.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ...

        someButton.setOnClickListener(this) // How do I refer to the `OnClickListener` implementation?
    }
}
```

How do I refer to the `OnClickListener` implementation in the above mentioned code snippet?

Comment: The multiple-inheritance tag should be removed, this is single inheritance and implementing an interface (Kotlin does not have multiple-inheritance)

Comment: If you are not adding the `Android` tag it is good to create a simplified question example that anyone can work with easily to answer your question.  I tried a mocked up version and see no error.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to implement `onClick(View)` function and change `onCreate` signature. After that code will looks like below:

```
public class SomeActivity() : Activity(), OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super<Activity>.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val someButton = Button(this)

        someButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        // TODO implement
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that. But still it says expected type is `OnClickListener` but found `SomeActivity`. I'm a little confused.

Comment: Show us your imports. Are you sure you are implementing the correct OnClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

Not wanting to create an Android project, I created a mock up of your classes and there are no errors using the code mentioned in another answer:

```
// mocked up classes

interface Bundle {}

open class Activity {
    open fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
}
interface View {}

interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(v: View)
}

open class Button(a: Activity) {
    fun setOnClickListener(o: OnClickListener) {}
}

// the usage, showing no error:

public class SomeActivity() : Activity(), OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super<Activity>.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val someButton = Button(this)

        someButton.setOnClickListener(this) // NO ERROR
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        // TODO implement
    }
}
```